# Twig: How to only show content if translation is given?

Tags: templates, twig, twig-filter

```html
{% for job in jobs %}
 {% if job.subject|trans %}
   <div> {{ job.info }} </div>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have three languages of translations only English being mandatory. ATM the job is shown no matter what Language is selected (if no other translation is given, twig uses the default en translation.
I want it to only show job info if the job translation in that language is given (if it exists in selected locale). How is this possible?

**Fixed issue**:

Issue was fixed with some back and forth in the controller. Not ideal but it works (isLocale($locale, $job) just checks in ORA translatable if jobs has a subject in given locale) :

```php
    public function indexAction(Request $request)

    {

        $repository = $this->getJobRepository();


        $jobs = $repository->findBy(['active' => true], ['sortOrder' => 'ASC']);


        return ['jobs' => $jobs];

        $locale = $request->getLocale();

        $localeJobs = array();

        foreach ($jobs as $job){

            if($this->isLocale($locale, $job)) array_push($localeJobs, $job);

        }


        return ['jobs' => $localeJobs];
    }
```

Comment: Do you have already see the [Fallback Translation Locales](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#fallback-translation-locales)?

Comment: Yes, my investigation led me to this documentation. Is it possible to 'disable' fallback?

Comment: try settings as an empty array as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61372701/2270041

Comment: Sadly it does not work :c The job's that are not translated into eg. italian are still displayed in default language.